# "Save as template"-link missing

Tags: 2016, site-template, team-sites

I am missing the "Save as template"-link in the site setting of a "Team Site".
But in the "SharePoint Designer" the feature is available and can be pressed (it is opening the correct page).

Site settings:

[image]

Design Manager:

[image]

Am i missing something?

System: SharePoint 2016

Comment: Is this a modern experience site?

Comment: No. It is a classic Team-Site without Publishing-Features.